# Правильно ли использовать setTimeoiut в качестве установки последовательности?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Можно ли использовать setTimeout в качестве установки последовательности? Или может есть лучшие варианты как это сделать?
Для примера вот небольшая функция:

```js
function showBlock() {  // smooth appearance / disappearance
  var block = document.getElementById('block');
  block.classList.toggle('active');
  
  if(block.classList.contains('active')) {
    block.style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(function () {
      block.style.opacity = 1;
    }, 0)
  }
  
  else {
    block.style.opacity = 0;
    setTimeout(function () {
      block.style.dispplay = 'none';
    }, 0)
  }
}
```

```css
#block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<button onclick = "showBlock()">Click on me</button>
<div id="block"></div>
```

Comment: Вы это делаете чтобы css transition отработал?

Comment: Да, для него. Но бывают и другие ситуации где необходимо установить последовательность. Так вот задался вопросом, можно ли таким образом делать?

Comment: Вообще-то есть события типа transitionEnd

Comment: с нулем setTimeout в следующем таске же выполнит все, поэтому у вас транзишен полностью не отработает ( поставьте больше, все равно будет скрываться в одно и тоже время )

Comment: @AlexeyTen transitionEnd ненадёжен и при некоторых обстоятельствах может не сработать, сам всегда использую setTimeout вместо него, он точно сработает

Comment: @andreymal я довольно часто использую transitionEnd. Можете рассказать, в каких случаях могут быть сбои?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko банальное - браузер не поддерживает transitionEnd. Небанальное - если ситуация сложилась так, что transition ничего не меняет и анимация на странице не проигрывается (например блок отобразили и тут же скрыли так, что он на странице даже моргнуть не успел), тогда transitionEnd тоже не запускается и display:none поставить некому

Comment: @andreymal понятно, спасибо.